# Touchpad access in Linux

Tags: linux, touch, touchpad

The problem is: How to access x,y,z coordinates of my touchpad?

Now that SHMConfig is disabled by default, I've found out that, in order to do it, I need to access a file from /dev/input/. Those files are, sadly, readable by root only. Is there any way to access the touchpad while in user-mode?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you access the pointing devices via the X11 system and the [X11 XInput extension](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/X11/Xinput.pdf). Only the X11 server will access the /dev/input file. The X11 server will allow many applications to share the input devices in a controlled manner.

You can find out what pointing devices are available with
[List X11 input devices](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XFreeDeviceList.3.html) and you can change which device is the (current) X pointer with [Change the pointer device](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XChangePointerDevice.3.html).